# Как вычесть номера телефонов из текста внутри тегов <p> во внешний файл, используя JS?

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток!

Заранее прошу меня извинить, если буду как-то невнятно излагать мысли. Я новичок в JS, помимо того пока только занимаюсь мануал тестированием и пишу тесты, используя ProtractorJS (знания в JS ограничены бесплатными курсами с codecademy, то есть почти ничего).

Для testData требуются номера мобильных телефонов, которые размещены на сайте в тегах *<td>*, *<p>*.

Пример:

```
<td>0970914975; vk.com/eu г.Киев ул.Короля 33а; test@yandex.ua Иванов Иван Иванович</td>
<p>Петров Петр Петрович, Чернигов, ОПРНВ, test@yandex.ru 0976253233</p>
```

Нужно написать скрипт, что бы считывались из всей страницы только номера мобильных телефонов и сохранялись списком (json, js, txt без разницы). 
Проштудировав Google, ничего толком не нашел (возможно не правильно ищу?). Прошу помощи опытных специалистов. Навести на путь истинный. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать.

Comment: Простая регулярка Вам поможет. А работать с файловой системой (т. е. сохранять) - это Вам к ноде.

Comment: Скачать можно и на клиентском js: http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server

Comment: @br3t, сформировать и предложить, но никак не сохранить. Но Вы правы.

Comment: Благодарю за наводку! Долго не мог понять как применить на практике, но знакомый помог кодом на Selenium'е

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение моей задачи:

```
/**
 * Created by Andrew Reznik on 3/15/2017. Selenium
 */
let webdrv = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdrv.By;
let fs = require('fs');
//Создаем переменную для массива
let content = [];

const SELENIUM_HOST = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub';
const URL = 'http://test.com/index.html';

let client = new webdrv.Builder()
    .usingServer(SELENIUM_HOST)
    .withCapabilities({browserName: 'firefox'})
    .build();

client.get(URL)
    .then(function () {
        return client.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[@id='wrapper']/div[@id='page']/div[@class='row'][4]"));

    })
    .then((elements) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) elements[i].getText()
            .then(function (text) {
                content.push(text.match(/\d{10}/g) + "\n");
            });
        return content;
    })
    .then(content =>
    fs.writeFile("phones.txt", content, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("The file was saved!");
    }));
```